# Is there an identity to solve for: $ \int \frac{dx}{(x^2+ \alpha^2)^2} $

Tags: integration

Is there an identity to solve for: $ \int \frac{dx}{(x^2+ \alpha^2)^2} $

Thanks in advance and more power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We wish to solve
$$
I=\int \frac{dx}{(x^2+ \alpha^2)^2}
$$
We can use a hyperbolic substitution of the form $x=\alpha\sinh \phi, dx=\alpha\cosh \phi d\phi$
$$
I=\int \frac{\alpha\cosh \phi d\phi}{(\alpha^2(\sinh^2 \phi+1))^{2}}=\frac{1}{\alpha^3}\int \frac{\cosh \phi d\phi}{\cosh^4 \phi}=\frac{1}{\alpha^3}\int \frac{d\phi}{\cosh^3 \phi}=\frac{1}{\alpha^3}\left( \arctan\big(\tanh \frac{\phi}{2}\big)+\frac{1}{2}\text{sech} \phi \tanh \phi + \mathcal{C}\right).
$$
Changing back to our original variable x using $\phi=\sinh^{-1}(x/\alpha)$ we obtain 
$$
I=\frac{ \frac{\alpha x}{\alpha^2+x^2}+\arctan(\frac{x}{\alpha})}{2\alpha^3}+\mathcal{C}.
$$
Note, you may find these useful for the future
$$
\tanh \big(\sinh^{-1}\frac{x}{\alpha}\big)=\frac{x}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+x^2}}, \ \ \text{sech}\big({\sinh^{-1} \frac{x}{\alpha}\big)= \frac{\alpha}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+x^2}}}, \ \alpha >0.
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Integrate by parts
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2+\alpha^2}=\frac{x}{x^2+\alpha^2}+2\int\frac{x^2\color{red}{+\alpha^2-\alpha^2}}{(x^2+\alpha^2)^2}dx$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#00f}{\large\int{\dd x  \over \pars{x^{2} + a^{2}}^{2}}}=
-\,{1 \over 2a}\,\partiald{}{a}\bracks{\int{\dd x  \over x^{2} + a^{2}}}
=-\,{1 \over 2a}\,\partiald{}{a}\bracks{{1 \over a}
\int{\dd\pars{x/a}  \over \pars{x/a}^{2} + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over 2a}\,\partiald{}{a}\bracks{{1 \over a}\,\arctan\pars{x \over a}}
=-\,{1 \over 2a}\bracks{-\,{1 \over a^{2}}\,\arctan\pars{x \over a}
+ {1 \over a}\,{-\pars{x/a^{2}} \over \pars{x/a}^{2} + 1}}
\\[3mm]&=\color{#00f}{\large%
{1 \over 2a^{3}}\bracks{\arctan\pars{x \over a}
+ {a\,x \over x^{2} + a^{2}}}} + \mbox{a constant}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using [Trigonometric substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution), set $$x=\alpha\tan\theta$$

Then  use Double Angle formula $\displaystyle\displaystyle\cos2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1\iff\cos^2\theta=\frac{1+\cos2\theta}2$

Now, $\displaystyle\int2\cos2\theta\ d\theta=\sin2\theta+K=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}+K$ where $K$ is an arbitrary constant

Comment: @Downvoter, can you please pinpoint the mistake here?